# What do repopulation and expansion mean in stem cell biology?

Tags: terminology, stem-cells

I was studying a lecture on the effects of cytokines on hematopoiesis, and it uses these two terms often in the context of the effects of regulators on hematopoietic stem cells:

- All repopulating bone marrow HSCs express a fibroblast growth factor (FGF) receptor that supports HSC expansion
- TPO may has a role in promoting the survival of repopulating HSCs, however, it contributes to both generation and expansion of HSCs during definitive hematopoiesis.
- Etc.

I looked online and honestly struggled to find any form of a definition on these two terms. They are used awfully alot though which makes it kinda weird too frankly.